# Let a,b and n be natural numbers. If a|n, b|n and g.c.d(a,b)=1 then prove that ab|n.

Tags: real-numbers

I am have difficulty carrying out the following proof:

Let *a*,*b* and *n* be natural numbers. If *a|n*, *b|n* and *g.c.d(a,b)=1* then prove that *ab|n*.

I understand that if *a|n* this implies *n=ca* for some natural number *c* and that *b|n* implies *n=mb* for some natural number *m*. I can also see that *g.c.d(a,b)=1* implies that *a* and *b* share no common prime factors.

Any tips or hints on how to solve above would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for letting us know. I will be sure to make a note of this. I was not aware that I was beholden to you and that you could order me around, but I guess I learn something new every day. Did you have a question, though? Because your post does not contain any.

Comment: Apologies Anturo, I have edited the question and added more detail.

Comment: Hint: $a|n$, so $n=ak$ for some $k$. $b|n$, so $b|ak$. But $\gcd(a,b)=1$, so...

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. Since *b|ak* and *gcd(a,b)=1* this implies that *b|k*, thus *k=mb* for some m. Substituting into *n=ak* gives *n=abm*, hence *ab|n*. I hope I am understanding this now! Thank you.